# How can I fit an interactive table using ioslides presentation and DT package?

Tags: r, r-markdown, dt, ioslides

I am new using the option from R Markdown that allows you to create presentations... and I was wondering how can I fit an interactive table (using `DT` package) in one slide of my presentation.

First of all, I don't know why the color changes from white to gray... The previous slide is white and the slide that it has the table, it is gray.

[image: image 1]

On the other hand, if I try to select other pages of the table ("click on number 6), the table gets bigger and I cannot change or see more elements of the table.

[image: image 2]

This is the code:

````
---
title: "Habits"
author: "John Doe"
date: "March 22, 2005"
output:
    ioslides_presentation:
      widescreen: true

---

# In the morning

## Getting up 

- Turn off alarm
- Get out of bed

# TABLE

```{r}
library(DT)
datatable(head(mtcars, n = nrow(mtcars)), options = list(pageLength = 5)) 
```
````

Does anyone know how to solve it?

[By the way, if you know about some tutorials using tables and markdown presentations, I will be grateful too.]

Thanks very much in advance

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the page is gray is because you are using heading 1 in your title (as `# TABLE`). On this template, main headings have gray background. Check the very first slide, `# In the Morning`, and you will see that it is also gray.

[image]

Note also that in this template the title is positioned in the lower left corner of the slide. That means that your title TABLES is behind your table. I assume that that is what is causing trouble with table when you try to change to page 6. Try using heading 2 for you title, like this:

````
---
title: "Habits"
author: "John Doe"
date: "March 22, 2005"
output:
    ioslides_presentation:
      widescreen: true

---

# In the morning

## Getting up 

- Turn off alarm
- Get out of bed

## TABLE


```{r }
library(DT)
datatable(head(mtcars, n = nrow(mtcars)), options = list(pageLength = 5)) 
```
````

Here is the result:

[image]

### EDIT

Adding extra info that you requested, and I had missed earlier. I like the theme `night` from reveal.js. Here is how my yaml look like.

```
---
title: ""
output: 
       
  revealjs::revealjs_presentation:
          theme: night
          center: true
---
```

You can find the name of other themes at https://revealjs.com/themes/.